# How to send multi part key value via http get

Tags: amazon-web-services, query-string, aws-serverless

I am trying to learn to use AWS Lambda, DynamoDB, and API Gateway.
I am able to set up a run a successful test of the Lambda that would take querystring parameters and returns the data from the database and I know I have the ability to access the Lambda from my API as I have created one to just return hello world.  However, I am stuck as to how to send the parameters I need to the Lambda.  These work fine from the Lambda test feature within Lambda.

```
 {
      "queryStringParameters": {
        "TableName": "Exams",
         "Key": {
          "ExamName": "MyFirstExam"
          }
      }
    }
```

However I can not seem to create a html query http://apiurl/route?parameters
as I have no idea how to send the Key.

I have tried everything I can think of here is just a sample of what I have tried

```
http://apiurl/route?TableName=Exams&Key=ExamName&ExamName=MyFirstExam
http://apiurl/route?TableName=Exams&key=ExamName&Keyvalue=MyFirstExam
http://apiurl/route?TableName=Exams&key=ExamName&value=MyFirstExam
http://apiurl/route?TableName=Exams&key=ExamName:MyFirstExam
```

but nothing has worked so I am wondering how do you send key = ExamName : MyfirstExam so that it is a part of the querystring parameters?

**UPDATE:**
I found that the rest api gave me more feed back and it looks like I need to use

````http://apiURL/Route?TableName= Exams&Key= { ExamName: MyFirstExam } ```

as this populates the querystring parameters.

`"queryStringParameters":{"TableName":"Exams","Key":"{ ExamName: MyFirstExam }"}`

However, I am still getting an error. That leads me to believe that I still may not have the format right. The problem is that when I used the same data in the test from within the lambda console it works and returns the data. When I use the querystring above which appears to be the same data as used in the lambda test it throws an error.

Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: The provided key element does not match the schema. So my Key is getting there as I get a status 200 and if I leave the key off of the querystring it throws and error that the key is missing but it appears to not be formatted correctly apparently or is it something else that I am missing. It appears to be the same as the format that is working in the Lambda test.
This works from the lambda test

`{ "queryStringParameters": { "TableName": "Exams", "Key": { "ExamName": "MyFirstExam" } } }`

this does not work from the API test

`"queryStringParameters":{"TableName":"Exams","Key":"{ ExamName: MyFirstExam }"}`

This is how I am formatting the querystring

`http://apiURL/Route?TableName= Exams&Key= { ExamName: MyFirstExam }`

How do I format a querystring so that it works from the API gateway?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most commonly used method of joining API Gateway and lambda is through `AWS_PROXY` **integration** between your API and your function.

With this type of [integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html):

> API Gateway applies a default mapping template to send the **entire request to the Lambda function** and transforms the output from the Lambda function to HTTP responses.

This means that every query parameter you provide through your API endpoint is going to be delivered directly into lambda function:

> This request **data includes** the request headers, **query string parameters**, URL path variables, payload, and API configuration data.

The `event` format your lambda function gets is described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format).

Comment: Yes, but how do you format the multi value Key parameter so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by having the key part already in the code and just now only need to pass a normal variable ExamName=Exam.

````
  var queryParameters ={
      TableName: request.TableName,
      Key:{
        "ExamName": request.ExamName
      },
  };```
````